# Simple html project with tailwind throws "Index of /" error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, git, tailwind-css

I do not completely understand the setting up and version control of projects. I created a project with tailwind which worked fine locally with an http-server plugin. I tried to create a gitlab repo and merge the two which sadly did not work out. Now I cannot start it locally anymore and I get following ERROR:

```
Index of /
    (drwxr-xr-x)    12-Jun-2023 15:33       .git/
    (drwxr-xr-x)    12-Jun-2023 15:34       .idea/
    (drwxr-xr-x)    12-Jun-2023 15:33       node_modules/
    (drwxr-xr-x)    12-Jun-2023 15:33       src/
    (drwxr-xr-x)    12-Jun-2023 13:21       tailwind/
    (-rw-r--r--)    12-Jun-2023 14:20   6.0k    .DS_Store
    (-rw-r--r--)    12-Jun-2023 15:35   134.6k  package-lock.json
    (-rw-r--r--)    12-Jun-2023 15:32   318B    package.json
    (-rw-r--r--)    12-Jun-2023 12:11   422B    tailwind.config.js
    (-rw-r--r--)    12-Jun-2023 15:35   437B    website.iml

Node.js v20.2.0/ http-server server running @ 127.0.0.1:8080
```

I read somewhere that my index.html cannot be found. It is located in the src folder though. The pulling and pushing to the repo also does not work yet. If I push to main it won't let me and if I push to another branch git is gone with all my files.

Please help. I'm already happy if I can make it work locally again.

Comment: What you're showing is not an error, it's a directory listing of files.  Based on the files shown, it looks like you're simply browsing the source code of your project.  Is that not the intent?  Does your project have some kind of build and/or deploy operation (likely a command in `package.json`)?  It's not clear to me specifically what you're asking, it just looks like you're confusing the source code with the published result.

Comment: Oh I see. The actual errors are that all files I included or require cannot be found since I copied everything to my repo. That includes jquery and all js, css files.
I do not have a build or deploy. @David

Comment: Are you expecting this repository to be the entire source code, or only the deployable artifacts?  It's really not clear what you're even trying to do, honestly.  But if the `index.html` file you're looking for is in the `src` folder then I imagine you'd either click on that folder or add `/src` to the URL.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you for your comments. I added commands to the package.json (as you mentioned) and added a .gitignore so it does not mess up the merge requests. @David

Answer (score 0):

If you struggle with something similar see comments for solution.